# How to prevent particular <div> action on clicking button in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to prevent particular `<div>` action on clicking button in AngularJS?

I have tried with `event.preventpropagation` on `on-click`.

Comment: include the relevant code, like what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

This should work `preventDefault`

```
<div ng-click="prevention($event)">DIV</div>

 $scope.prevention = function($event) {
  // our function body
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
}
```